# SELECT query with one or multiple IF statements in ABAP

Tags: sql, if-statement, select, abap, sap-erp

I'm working on a web service. I have a select statement like this (it has much more fields and 2 more joins than this but to keep it simple):

```
SELECT acdoca~augbl,
       open_amount,    "I need to add value to this field based on the IF statement below
       acdoca~koart
FROM acdoca
      LEFT JOIN bseg ON acdoca~belnr EQ bseg~belnr
                      AND acdoca~gjahr EQ bseg~gjahr
                      AND acdoca~buzei EQ bseg~buzei
                      AND acdoca~rbukrs EQ bseg~bukrs
INTO table @it_acdoca.
```

I need to add this IF statement:

```
IF bseg-KOART = 'D' or bseg-KOART = 'K' 
    IF acdoca-AUGBL is INITIAL THEN open_amount = DMBTR
        ELSE open_amount = 0
    ENDIF.
ELSE open_amount = 0
ENDIF.
```

I need an answer that won't trash the performance of the service. Since ACDOCA and BSEG are some of the biggest database tables in SAP. I tried using LOOP after SELECT and then adding this IF inside that LOOP but that destroyed the performance totally.

[This Is What IT_ACDOCA table should look like after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc4eM.png)

Hoping for a quick reply.
Best regards.

Comment: if you are concerned about ACDOCA performance, use [CTE](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/01/28/use-the-new-open-sql-to-get-company-account-and-monthly-gains-and-losses-and-balances-from-acdoca./) or [CDS](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/02/24/use-cds-view-to-get-company-account-and-monthly-gains-and-losses-and-balances-from-acdoca./)

Comment: Yes, do not use ACDOCA (or any other table) directly! It's very large, has a lot of semantics inside and is also constantly changing. You will either (a) not get the results you want or (b) your logic will stop working in the future or (c) the performance is terrible. Instead use one of the released CDS entities on top, such as I_SalesOrderItem or the alike, specific to your usecase. With this you have (1) proper authorization checks, (2) clear migration paths in case something changes and (3) you don't have to maintain the joins :)

Answer (score 2):

```
DATA: BEGIN OF it_acdoca  OCCURS 0,
        augbl       TYPE acdoca-augbl,
        open_amount TYPE bseg-dmbtr,
        koart       TYPE acdoca-koart.
DATA: END OF it_acdoca.

SELECT acdoca~augbl,
       CASE WHEN ( bseg~koart EQ 'D' OR bseg~koart EQ 'K' ) AND acdoca~AUGBL is INITIAL THEN dmbtr
         ELSE 0
   END AS open_amount,
       acdoca~koart
FROM acdoca
      LEFT JOIN bseg ON acdoca~belnr EQ bseg~belnr
                      AND acdoca~gjahr EQ bseg~gjahr
                      AND acdoca~buzei EQ bseg~buzei
                      AND acdoca~rbukrs EQ bseg~bukrs
INTO TABLE @it_acdoca.
```

If your version not supported **CASE** you can add your statement to JOIN side like below.

```
SELECT acdoca~augbl,
       dmbtr AS open_amount,
       acdoca~koart
FROM acdoca
      LEFT JOIN bseg ON acdoca~belnr EQ bseg~belnr
                      AND acdoca~gjahr EQ bseg~gjahr
                      AND acdoca~buzei EQ bseg~buzei
                      AND acdoca~rbukrs EQ bseg~bukrs
                      AND ( bseg~koart EQ 'D' OR bseg~koart EQ 'K' )
                      AND acdoca~AUGBL is INITIAL
INTO TABLE @it_acdoca.
```

Comment: Dear mkysoft,   
thank you for your answer, the part with case statement solved my problem. Second part wouldn't work for me bcuz I have many more fields in select that would be effected by adding those rows in JOIN. Nevertheless, thanks for help!